# German letter 'ü' lost in translation in Django web application

Tags: django, translation

In our Django web project we use german translations from a '.mo' file. One of the translation words as follows.

> msgid "Back"
>
> msgstr "Zurück"

This is used in text field of buttons. What I get in button is  `'<span class="button">Zurck</span>'` instead of '**Zurück**'

In other translation texts letter 'ü' is used many times and does not get missing but only this one 'ü' gets lost. What can be the problem here?

Comment: Do any other words from the same `.mo` file get shown correctly or this `.mo` file has only this translation inside it?

Comment: I presume Python 2?

Comment: Yes python 2.7. There are other words with letter 'ü' but there are no other sentences or words containing 'zurück'.

Comment: Try defining your string as unicode, e.g., `string_to_translate = u'Zurück'`.